# Sending parameters to URL

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I'm sending the contents of a few textboxes to my website using the `HttpClient`. My `PHP` script inserts the data in a database.
But after clicking the btnSubmit-button, it runs the code but nothing is added to my database and no exceptions are thrown. What's wrong with my code?

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class Submit2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public Submit2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string parameter = string.Empty;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("barcode", out parameter))
            {
                Barcode.Text = parameter;
            }
        }

        public static int typeConnection()
        {
            switch (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)
            {
                default:
                    return 0;
                case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
                    return 1;
                case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
                    return 1;
                case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.None:
                    return 2;
            }
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (typeConnection() < 2)
                {
                    string URI = "http://cocktailpws.net23.net/requests/add_contribution.php";
                    string myParameters = "barcode=" + Barcode.Text + "&booze=" + Name.Text + "&email=" + Email.Text;
                    sendData(URI, myParameters);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No database connection could be established. Please check your internet connection and try again.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception myExc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
            }
        }

        public async void sendData(string URI, string myParameters)
        {
            using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await hc.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(myParameters));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['barcode']) && isset($_POST['booze']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    include_once "../inc/inc_db.php";
    $booze = sqlesc($_POST['booze']);
    $barcode = sqlesc($_POST['barcode']);
    $email = sqlesc($_POST['email']);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $query = "INSERT INTO contr_barcode(booze,barcode,email,datum) VALUES ('$booze','$barcode','$email',$date')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way you're going to solve this is by stepping through it. Have you tried debugging it properly?

Comment: @DeeMac Yes I did. Followed it using breakpoints. I think there's something wrong with my PHP approach rather than the c#..

Comment: My knowledge of PHP is limited, but I'd imagine the same applies; you need to step through it.

Comment: @DeeMac Took a closer look at my locals and discovered `hc` had an error: baseAddress Cannot fetch the value of field 'baseAddress' because information about the containing class is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the values formatted as if you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` however, by default StringContent will declare the content-type as `text/plain`.  It is possible that the PHP framework is not parsing the content correctly because it thinks you are just sending unformatted plain text.

You could either change the content-type of the `StringContent` object, or you could use the `UrlEncodedFormContent` class. e.g.

```
    var content = new StringContent(myParameters);
    content.Headers.Content-Type = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var response = await hc.PostAsync(URI, content);
```